# RaphaelJS:Text around path not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

I have been working with [VectorEditorJS](http://jsvectoreditor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html).Using it for TShirt designing web application.I have added few lines of code to enhance a feature which would let me stylize text by curving it around a `path` .A lot of the code is borrowed from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/4UykA/).

Now this code was working fine until i utilised some piece of source code from [this feeds](http://2hats.net/_box/raphael/m.rss.html) source,to group the `text` and `path` inside a `<g>` tag.Now when i trigger the code to curve the text,the text and path just vanishes from the canvas.

**Rendered SVG which is not visible (you can try this in your browser):**

```
<svg height="490" version="1.1" width="513" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" font-size="0px" font-family="Comic Sans MS " stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 0px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';"><tspan dy="50" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Text</tspan></text><g><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M152.02796,220.79435C158.08887000000001,228.37049000000002,165.15994,235.44156,165.15994,235.44156L181.32238,245.54308L207.58635,253.6243L235.87062,258.16999L260.61936000000003,260.1903L287.38840000000005,258.67507L307.59145000000007,254.63446000000002L333.3503400000001,247.56339000000003L351.5330900000001,239.48217000000002L369.21076000000005,224.32988000000003" stroke-opacity="0" id="pathPF2116" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text x="152.0323993235795" y="220.79989884025497" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" font-size="118px" stroke-width="3" font-family="Comic Sans MS " fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.6247,0.7808,-0.7808,0.6247,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 118px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;"><tspan dy="220.79989884025497" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">P</tspan></text><text x="189.59641501815253" y="248.08893644399512" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" font-size="118px" stroke-width="3" font-family="Comic Sans MS " fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.9558,0.2941,-0.2941,0.9558,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 118px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;"><tspan dy="248.08893644399512" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">o</tspan></text><text x="235.80833370414376" y="258.15997969419357" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" font-size="118px" stroke-width="3" font-family="Comic Sans MS " fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.9873,0.1587,-0.1587,0.9873,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 118px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;"><tspan dy="258.15997969419357" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">p</tspan></text><text x="283.0874906136036" y="258.91851791331885" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" font-size="118px" stroke-width="3" font-family="Comic Sans MS " fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.9984,-0.0565,0.0565,0.9984,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 118px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;"><tspan dy="258.91851791331885" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">p</tspan></text><text x="329.2829813479077" y="248.67992016663572" text-anchor="start" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="#4255ff" fill="#ff73a6" id="lpathPF2116" font-size="118px" stroke-width="3" font-family="Comic Sans MS " fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.9643,-0.2647,0.2647,0.9643,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 118px; line-height: normal; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;"><tspan dy="248.67992016663572" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">y</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBVCL/) of the above.

**Code which manipulates a visible text to curve around a specific path:**

```
function manipulate(editorObj, selection,stylePath) {

    var localCopy = editorObj.selected[0]; //.clone(); 

    var _group = editorObj.draw.set();
    var path = editorObj.draw.path(stylePath).attr("stroke", "transparent"),
    message = localCopy[0].textContent,
    message_length = 0,
    letters = [],
    places = [],
    ratio,
    fontsize,
    letter,
    c = 0,
    p;

    _group.push(path);
    var dt = new Date();
    var dtStr=dt.getHours().toString() + dt.getSeconds().toString();
    var idOfNode = "pathPF"+dtStr;
    path.node.id = idOfNode;
    var group = document.createElementNS("svg", "g");

    //since not every letter is the same width, get the placement for each letter along the length of the string
    //however, Raphael appears to group the width of letters into intervals of 4px, so this won't be perfect        
   function Cr(el) {
       group.appendChild(el.node);
   }
   Cr(path);
    for (; c < message.length; c += 1) {
        letter = editorObj.draw.text(0, 0, message[c]).attr({ "text-anchor": "start" });
        Cr(letter);
        _group.push(letter);
        letters.push(letter);
        places.push(message_length);
        //spaces get a width of 0, so set min at 4px
        message_length += Math.max(4, letter.getBBox().width);
    }
    letter.node.id = "l" + idOfNode;


$("#l" + idOfNode).after("</g>");

ratio = path.getTotalLength() / message_length;
fontsize = 10 * ratio;

for (c = 0; c < letters.length; c += 1) {

    letters[c].attr("font-size", fontsize + "px");
    letters[c].attr("stroke-width", localCopy.attr("stroke-width"));
    letters[c].attr("font-family", localCopy.attr("font-family"));
    letters[c].attr("fill", localCopy.attr("fill"));
    letters[c].attr("stroke", localCopy.attr("stroke"));
    letters[c].attr("stroke-width", localCopy.attr("stroke-width"));
    letters[c].attr("fill-opacity", localCopy.attr("fill-opacity"));
    letters[c].attr("stroke-opacity", localCopy.attr("stroke-opacity"));
    // letters[c].attr("font-family", localCopy.attr("font-family"));
    p = path.getPointAtLength(places[c] * ratio);
    //there does appear to be a bug in p.alpha around 180. Here's the fix
    letters[c].attr({ x: p.x, y: p.y, transform: 'r' + (p.alpha < 180 ? p.alpha + 180 : p.alpha) });
}
var svgdoc = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svgdoc.appendChild(group);

localCopy.remove();
editorObj.unselect();}
```

Can someone help me get there?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to add a `viewBox` (using `setViewBox()` in Raphaël), arriving at something like http://jsfiddle.net/dBVCL/1/.

Comment: But,I get http://jsfiddle.net/SX4JY/ which is proper without using `<g>` manipulation technique.(without viewbox)Can you tell me why ? Isnt the `<g>` giving problems,if yes then why? Thanks for the help

Comment: Some of the text has font-size="0px", is that intentional?

Comment: yes.actually its beginning with fontsize "0px" and `onMouseMove` its increasing it.Look at line 393 here.https://code.google.com/p/jsvectoreditor/source/browse/trunk/editor.js

Answer (score 0):

Some things I think are errors in your code:

```
var group = document.createElementNS("svg", "g");
```

This should be:

```
var group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
```

And this looks just plain wrong to me:

```
$("#l" + idOfNode).after("</g>");
```

You should never have to insert closing tags manually like this.

Comment: theres probably no other way to insert `<g>` tags via raphael.Is there? before you think,i need `<g>` element and not `paper.set`

Comment: before drawing `<g>` i have this :http://jsfiddle.net/23eCc/ after manipulating `<g>` i have this:http://jsfiddle.net/P9sM7/ while it should have curved on the like of this:http://jsfiddle.net/SX4JY/

Comment: Unless you use the proper svg namespace (first argument to createElementNS) then the created element will be an unknown element to svg, and that prevents rendering of that element and all of its children.

Comment: Doesnt solve the problem.I can see some of the elements now but others are overflowing out of my canvas.Wonder why!

Comment: Verify that you're placing the elements correctly. I'd recommend using `setViewBox()` for defining the coordinate space, but it's up to you to decide. Either way you'll need to keep your shapes within the defined area (either the viewBox area, or the canvas area).